# Graph Execution Error -> Getting this error while trying to train a ResNet50 model on colab

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to train a CNN model on Google Colab

here's my code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path
import os.path
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
from tensorflow.keras.layers import GlobalAveragePooling2D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, classification_report



image_dir = Path('/content/dataset')
filepaths = list(image_dir.glob(r'**/*.jpg'))
labels = list(map(lambda x: os.path.split(os.path.split(x)[0])[1], filepaths))

filepaths = pd.Series(filepaths, name='Filepath').astype(str)
labels = pd.Series(labels, name='Label')

images = pd.concat([filepaths, labels], axis=1)
num_class = images.Label.value_counts().count()

train_df, test_df = train_test_split(images, train_size=0.7, shuffle=True, random_state=1)
train_generator = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
    preprocessing_function=tf.keras.applications.resnet50.preprocess_input,
    validation_split=0.2)

test_generator = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
    preprocessing_function=tf.keras.applications.resnet50.preprocess_input)
train_images = train_generator.flow_from_dataframe(
    dataframe=train_df,
    x_col='Filepath',
    y_col='Label',
    target_size=(224, 224),
    color_mode='rgb',
    class_mode='categorical',
    batch_size=32,
    shuffle=True,
    seed=42,
    subset='training'
)

val_images = train_generator.flow_from_dataframe(
    dataframe=train_df,
    x_col='Filepath',
    y_col='Label',
    target_size=(224, 224),
    color_mode='rgb',
    class_mode='categorical',
    batch_size=32,
    shuffle=True,
    seed=42,
    subset='validation'
)

test_images = test_generator.flow_from_dataframe(
    dataframe=test_df,
    x_col='Filepath',
    y_col='Label',
    target_size=(224, 224),
    color_mode='rgb',
    class_mode='categorical',
    batch_size=32,
    shuffle=False
)
pretrained_model = tf.keras.applications.resnet50.ResNet50(
                    input_shape=(224, 224, 3),
                    include_top=False,
                    weights=None,
                    pooling='avg')

pretrained_model.trainable = False

inputs = pretrained_model.input
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(pretrained_model.output)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(50, activation='relu')(x)
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_class, activation='softmax')(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
print(model.summary())
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
callbacks = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss',patience=3,restore_best_weights=True)
history = model.fit(train_images,validation_data=val_images,epochs=25,callbacks=[callbacks])


model.save('my_model.h5')
score = model.evaluate(test_images)
print('Test loss:', score[0])
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])
```

I'm getting the following error :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-30-e1f6c12218f2> in <cell line: 84>()
     82 model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
     83 callbacks = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss',patience=3,restore_best_weights=True)
---> 84 history = model.fit(train_images,validation_data=val_images,epochs=25,callbacks=[callbacks])
     85 
     86 

1 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     50   try:
     51     ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 52     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
     53                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     54   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:

InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node 'categorical_crossentropy/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
      return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
    File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
      exec(code, run_globals)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
      app.launch_new_instance()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 992, in launch_instance
      app.start()
```

The model is being trained properly on a local pc but it fails to do so on colab

Any fixes ?

I tried running the same thing on Kaggle , but I got the same error over there too

And there were other similar posts but none of them had answers